# Meaning of $\gg$ in Hartshorne "Algebraic geometry"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation

I'm wondering what is the meaning of the symbol $\gg$ in *Algebraic Geomtry* by Robin Hartshorne. For example, in the definition of numerical polynomial:

> A numerical polynomial is a polynomial $P(z) \in \mathbb{Q}[z]$ such that $P(n) \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $n \gg 0$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 4):

It means, "for all sufficiently large integers $n$."